# Problem with non-nullable type after updating of the version of sdk in async request

Tags: flutter, dart

there was such problem after updating of the version of sdk, asks to consider null security.In the string :
"Future    makeRequest() async {"
Error:
"The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type"

```html
Future<String>   makeRequest() async {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);


    String url = global.urlVar;

    Map map = {
      "object":  global.nameObj,
      "type":  global.typesOp,
    };

    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();


    _isButtonDisabled = false;

    if (200 == response.statusCode  )  {

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Status_Obj())
      );
    }
    else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Error_Auth()),
      );
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function return type is specified as `String`, but it is not returning anything.

Replace `Future<String>` with `Future<void>` or return a `String` value.